# Android custom notification not displaying

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications

I tried to create a custom notification layout on android 11.
The notification is created, but the content is empty.
Could you please telle me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

**App Code:**

```
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    notificationIntent, 0);

            RemoteViews notificationLayout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notif_layout);
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
                    .setContent(notificationLayout)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_attestinator)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .build();
            startForeground(1, notification);
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/notif_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:translationY="16dp"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_av_timer_24" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notif_timer_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="xx:xx"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:translationY="14dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the solution:
it was a color pb: when I forced the text color to android:white, the text appeared!